# Deep linking not working from the Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to enable deep linking from custom open graph stories.  I have gone through the instructions listed

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links

Deep linking works fine when I click from the Facebook timeline to the actual story post page and then click the object button.  If I click the object button on the timeline itself, the url is NOT handled and instead is open directly in the Facebook webview.

This may be because I don't have a web platform added on my App Dashboard.
Facebook documentation reads

> *Deep linking in Open Graph stories*  If you're deep linking from an Open
>   Graph story published from your app, you will need to go through one
>   more step.
>
> ...
>
> If you HAVEN'T already added a website for this app, in the App
>   Dashboard, inside your app's settings, click on ''Add platform'', and
>   select ''Website''. Then in any of the fields (either ''Site URL'' or
>   ''Mobile site URL''), fill in your subdomain. **It doesn't matter if you
>   don't have a website that you're integrating with Facebook, this will
>   register this subdomain for use with your native app**.

However, when I try to add a the url in app settings (the screenshots match those in the documentation), my open graph submission is rejected by Facebook with the note:

> Your app does not qualify for the submitted platform. In the app
>   settings tab, please remove platforms without Facebook integration.
>   Canvas or page tab apps cannot redirect users, and websites must
>   properly integrate Facebook login.

Anybody been through this before and can lend some guidance? I am very much confused by the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deep-linking started working on its own about a week later without any changes on my part.